# coloring a case in a primefaces datatable by a condition

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable, styles

I have a column named credit and I want this to be colored red if it contains "+" sign and red if it's a "-" sign. here is my table

```
<h:form>
    <p:dataTable value="#{accountBean.accounts}" var="account" rows="4">
        <p:column headerText="IBAN">
            <h:outputText value="#{account.iban}"></h:outputText>
        </p:column>
        <p:column style="#{account.solde = + ? 'color: green' : 'color: red'}">
            <h:outputText value="#{account.solde}"> </h:outputText>
        </p:column>
        <p:column headerText="Creation Date">
            <h:outputText value="#{account.date_creation}">
                <f:convertDateTime pattern="dd-MM-yyyy" />
            </h:outputText>
        </p:column>
        <p:column headerText="Type">
            <h:outputText value="#{account.type}"> </h:outputText>
        </p:column>
        <p:column>
            <p:commandButton value="transactions history" action="#{transactionBean.init(account)}" update="idTransactionForm"></p:commandButton>
        </p:column>
    </p:dataTable>
</h:form>
```

This function is incorrect **`style="#{account.solde = + ? 'color: green' : 'color: red'}"`** because its condition is for just a + or - sign. But I want +.... and -....

Comment: use this instead of `style` : `rowStyleClass="#{entity.elementBoolean ? 'redClass' : null}" ` it most be a boolean value if you want i can give more informations and explications about it , and of corse redClass is a css

Answer (score 0):

you can perform something like that using the following step

***Step 1: Creating redClass Css***

go to your css file and add

```
.redClass{
background: #ee5f5b;
cursor: pointer;
}
```

every time you call this element it changes backgroud color

***Step 2 : use it in your column***

you have to use a boolean condition to call it (that mean's to have a true or false condition) like if my list is empty or my value is equal to something

```
 <p:column rowStyleClass="#{account.condition = ? 'redClass' : null ">
        <h:outputText value="#{account.solde}"> 
         </h:outputText>
 </p:column>
```

that's mean if the condition is true it will use `'redClass'` else it will be normal `null`

Hope that helped you.

Comment: Please correct the errors in your code, you make almost the identical error the OP makes and why his conditional styling does not work (it should work in the way he/she uses the style attribute)

Comment: but i've tested my solution before i posted it,how to add an image of the result ?!? (we can make it like this in an answer)

Comment: thank you @Yagami. it actually worked. and the rowstyleclass is what i really needed.

Comment: @javaManiac don't forget to make it as an aswer