# How to update a primefaces datatable row after cell editing?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

In my datatable depending on the column "Délai action", the other columns have to be in red when no date is in.
The last column has a yellow / orange / red ball icon depending on the date.
So how to update the row and then show the columns in red or not and the corresponding color ball ?

I tried different things like :

```
<p:ajax event="cellEdit" listener="#{prospectionForm.enregistrer}" update="cmpTableMandats"/>
```

Or also in my enregistrer() method :
    `RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update(table.getClientId(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()) + ":" + event.getRowIndex() + ":objet");`

Here is the datatable :

```
<p:dataTable id="cmpTableMandats" value="#{prospectionForm.listMandats}"
                        var="mandat" rows="50" rowKey="#{mandat.id}"
                        scrollable="true" scrollHeight="440"
                        editable="true" editMode="cell" 
                        emptyMessage="#{msg['AucuneDonneeAAfficher']}"
                        paginator="true" paginatorPosition="bottom"
                        paginatorTemplate=" {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"
                        rowsPerPageTemplate="50,100,200,300"
                        style="margin-top:20px">

                        <p:ajax event="cellEdit" listener="#{prospectionForm.enregistrerModification}" update=""/>

                        <p:column headerText="#{msg['Numero']}" style="width:12%">
                            <h:outputText value="#{mandat.numero}" styleClass="#{(mandat.fluxProspectionCi eq 'ETABLIR_OFFRE' or mandat.fluxProspectionCi eq 'A_RELANCER') and mandat.dateActionProspection == null ? 'red' : null}"/>
                        </p:column>

                        <p:column headerText="#{msg['AbregeDirecteur']}" style="width:4%">
                            <h:outputText value="#{mandat.coordinateur.initiales}" styleClass="#{(mandat.fluxProspectionCi eq 'ETABLIR_OFFRE' or mandat.fluxProspectionCi eq 'A_RELANCER') and mandat.dateActionProspection == null ? 'red' : null}"/>
                        </p:column>

                        <p:column headerText="#{msg['AbregeChefDeProjet']}" style="width:4%">
                            <h:outputText value="#{mandat.chefProjet.initiales}" styleClass="#{(mandat.fluxProspectionCi eq 'ETABLIR_OFFRE' or mandat.fluxProspectionCi eq 'A_RELANCER') and mandat.dateActionProspection == null ? 'red' : null}"/>
                        </p:column>

                        <!-- Affiche la localité pré-enregistrée ou la localité libre -->
                        <p:column headerText="#{msg['Localite']}" style="width:15%">
                            <h:outputText value="#{mandat.listMandatLocaliteToString}"
                                rendered="#{not empty mandat.listMandatLocalite}" styleClass="#{(mandat.fluxProspectionCi eq 'ETABLIR_OFFRE' or mandat.fluxProspectionCi eq 'A_RELANCER') and mandat.dateActionProspection == null ? 'red' : null}"/>
                            <h:outputText value="#{mandat.localiteLibre}"
                                rendered="#{not empty mandat.localiteLibre}" styleClass="#{(mandat.fluxProspectionCi eq 'ETABLIR_OFFRE' or mandat.fluxProspectionCi eq 'A_RELANCER') and mandat.dateActionProspection == null ? 'red' : null}"/>
                        </p:column>

                        <p:column headerText="#{msg['AbregeMaitreOuvrage']}" style="width:20%">
                            <h:outputText value="#{mandat.listMandatIdentiteToString}" styleClass="#{(mandat.fluxProspectionCi eq 'ETABLIR_OFFRE' or mandat.fluxProspectionCi eq 'A_RELANCER') and mandat.dateActionProspection == null ? 'red' :  null}"/>
                        </p:column>

                        <p:column headerText="#{msg['Objet']}" style="width:30%">
                            <h:outputText id="objet" value="#{mandat.objet}" styleClass="#{(mandat.fluxProspectionCi eq 'ETABLIR_OFFRE' or mandat.fluxProspectionCi eq 'A_RELANCER') and mandat.dateActionProspection == null ? 'red' : null}"/>
                        </p:column>

                        <p:column headerText="#{msg['CHF']}" style="width:10%; text-align:right">
                            <p:cellEditor>
                                <f:facet name="output">
                                    <h:outputText value="#{mandat.montantHonorairesFrais}" rendered="#{mandat.montantHonorairesFrais != 0.0}" styleClass="#{(mandat.fluxProspectionCi eq 'ETABLIR_OFFRE' or mandat.fluxProspectionCi eq 'A_RELANCER') and mandat.dateActionProspection == null ? 'red' : null}">
                                        <f:convertNumber pattern="#,##0.00" locale="fr_CH"/>
                                    </h:outputText>
                                </f:facet>
                                <f:facet name="input">
                                    <p:inputText value="#{mandat.montantHonorairesFrais}"
                                            converterMessage="Cannot convert to double.">
                                        <f:convertNumber pattern="#,##0.00" locale="fr_CH"/>
                                    </p:inputText>
                                </f:facet>
                            </p:cellEditor>
                        </p:column>

                        <p:column headerText="#{msg['EtapeActuelle']}" style="width:13%">
                            <p:cellEditor>
                                <f:facet name="output">
                                    <h:outputText value="#{mandat.fluxProspectionCi.nom}" styleClass="#{(mandat.fluxProspectionCi eq 'ETABLIR_OFFRE' or mandat.fluxProspectionCi eq 'A_RELANCER') and mandat.dateActionProspection == null ? 'red' : null}"/>
                                </f:facet>
                                <f:facet name="input">
                                    <p:selectOneMenu value="#{mandat.fluxProspectionCi}">
                                        <f:selectItems value="#{prospectionForm.listFluxProspection}"/>
                                    </p:selectOneMenu>
                                </f:facet>
                            </p:cellEditor>
                        </p:column>

                        <p:column headerText="#{msg['Remarque']}" style="width:30%">
                            <p:cellEditor>
                                <f:facet name="output">
                                    <h:outputText value="#{mandat.remarqueProspection}" styleClass="#{(mandat.fluxProspectionCi eq 'ETABLIR_OFFRE' or mandat.fluxProspectionCi eq 'A_RELANCER') and mandat.dateActionProspection == null ? 'red' : null}"/>
                                </f:facet>
                                <f:facet name="input">
                                    <p:inputTextarea value="#{mandat.remarqueProspection}"/>
                                </f:facet>
                            </p:cellEditor>
                        </p:column>

                        <p:column id="cmpDateAction" headerText="#{msg['Delai']} #{msg['Action']}" style="width:10%">
                            <p:cellEditor>
                                <f:facet name="output">
                                    <h:outputText value="#{mandat.dateActionProspection}" styleClass="#{(mandat.fluxProspectionCi eq 'ETABLIR_OFFRE' or mandat.fluxProspectionCi eq 'A_RELANCER') and mandat.dateActionProspection == null ? 'red' : null}">
                                        <f:convertDateTime pattern="dd.MM.yy"/>
                                    </h:outputText>
                                </f:facet>
                                <f:facet name="input">
                                    <p:calendar id="cmpDate"
                                        value="#{mandat.dateActionProspection}" showOn="true"
                                        pattern="dd.MM.yyyy" mask="true" locale="fr" styleClass="myInputClass">
                                    </p:calendar>
                                </f:facet>
                            </p:cellEditor>
                        </p:column>

                        <p:column headerText="" style="width:10%;">
                            <h:graphicImage id="un" rendered="#{mandat.dateProspectionDepassee}" value="/resources/images/icones/rwb/ball_red.png"/>
                            <h:graphicImage id="deux" rendered="#{mandat.dateProspectionAujourdhui}" value="/resources/images/icones/rwb/ball_orange.png"/>
                            <h:graphicImage id="trois" rendered="#{not mandat.dateProspectionDepassee and not mandat.dateProspectionAujourdhui and mandat.dateProspectionDans5JoursouMoins}" value="/resources/images/icones/rwb/ball_yellow.png"/>
                        </p:column>

                        <f:facet name="footer">  
                            #{fn:length(prospectionForm.listMandats)} #{msg['MandatsEnregistres']}  
                        </f:facet>
                    </p:dataTable>`
```

But nothing works fine
[image]

Thanks in advance

Primefaces 6.0 / JSF 2.3

Comment: did you see this post [Color row by condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42768759/coloring-a-case-in-a-primefaces-datatable-by-a-condition/42786061#42786061) ?!?

Comment: yes I did but the problem is "How to update a primefaces datatable row after cell editing?". Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Updating entire <p:dataTable> on complete of <p:ajax event="cellEdit">](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19548838/updating-entire-pdatatable-on-complete-of-pajax-event-celledit)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please use `p:remoteCommand`

Explanation can be found in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19927578/8079165) by @BalusC

For more information about `p:remoteCommand`, please refer to Primefaces showcase [RemoteCommand](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/ajax/remoteCommand.xhtml).

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

You can update a specific row using the `@row(n}` selector in combination with a `<p:remoteCommand>`. PrimeFaces Support showed me this:

https://primefaces.github.io/primefaces/12_0_0/#/core/searchexpression?id=primefaces-selectors-pfs

For this you save the current row index in your cell event listener like:

```
public void onCellEdit(final CellEditEvent<T> event)
{
    this.cellEditRowIndex = event.getRowIndex();
}
```

Create a remote command to use that index:

```
<!-- update specific row on cell edit event -->
<p:remoteCommand id="remoteCommandOnCellEdit"
    name="remoteCommandOnCellEdit" 
    update="#{bean.model.cellEditRowIndex eq null ? null : 
        'tableId:@row('.concat(bean.model.cellEditRowIndex).concat(')')}" />
```

Update and fire the remoteCommand in the cellEdit definition:

```
<p:ajax event="cellEdit" listener="#{bean.model.onCellEdit}" 
    process="@this" update=":growl, @form:remoteCommandOnCellEdit"
    oncomplete="remoteCommandOnCellEdit();"/>
```

Not a perfect solution cause there is a significant delay with a second request to update the row and other dependent cell values but its working.

**Update programmatically in cellEdit listener? - not working!**

I also tried using `@row(n)` inside the `onCellEdit` java listener function to update the row programmatically but it does not work. PrimeFaces still interferes the response only allowing the cell content to be updated.

```
public void onCellEdit(final CellEditEvent<T> event)
{
    // update row with ajax explicit - not working - PrimeFaces interferes in response only updating cell content
    if (event.getSource() instanceof DataTable)
    {
        final DataTable table = (DataTable) event.getSource();

        final String rowClientId = table.getClientId() + ":@row(" + event.getRowIndex() + ")";

        final String[] clientIds = SearchExpressionFacade
            .resolveClientIds(context, context.getViewRoot(), rowClientId).split(" ");
        for (final String clientId : clientIds)
            context.getPartialViewContext().getRenderIds().add(clientId);
    }
}
```